# How to write this C++17 static constexpr method in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++17, template-meta-programming

What is the most concise way to write the below `static constexpr size_t Foo<>::sum()` method in C++11? This works fine with C++17 compilers, but I'm looking for a way that works on g++, clang, and Visual Studio 2015 in C++11 mode.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T,size_t N>
class Foo
{
  public:
    static constexpr size_t sum();
};

template<typename>
struct is_foo : std::false_type { };
template<typename T,size_t N>
struct is_foo<Foo<T,N>> : std::true_type { };

template<typename T,size_t N>
constexpr size_t Foo<T,N>::sum()
{
    if constexpr (is_foo<T>::value)
        return N + T::sum();
    else
        return N;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr size_t sum = Foo<Foo<Foo<double,3>,4>,5>::sum(); // 12 = 3+4+5
    std::cout << "sum = " << sum << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compile and run:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 7.3.1 20180303 (Red Hat 7.3.1-5)
...
$ g++ -std=c++17 sum.cpp
$ ./a.out 
sum = 12
```

I'm able to write an external functor for `sum()` that accomplishes this, but I would really like for it to be a `static constexpr` member function as above. Is this even possible in C++11?

Comment: You're just asking how to replace the `if constexpr` then, right? `enable_if`?

Comment: I tried SFINAE with `constexpr typename std::enable_if<is_foo<T>::value,size_t>::type Foo<T,N>::sum()` but am getting the error `prototype for 'constexpr typename std::enable_if<is_foo< <template-parameter-1-1> >::value, long unsigned int>::type Foo<T, N>::sum()' does not match any in class 'Foo<T, N>'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd write it as following:

```
template <typename>
struct foo_sum : std::integral_constant<size_t, 0> {};

template <typename T, size_t N>
struct foo_sum<Foo<T, N>> : std::integral_constant<size_t, foo_sum<T>::value + N> {};
```

It can be wrapped into a `static constexpr` function easily:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
constexpr size_t Foo<T, N>::sum()
{
    return foo_sum<Foo<T, N>>::value;
}
```

Comment: This does work. On Visual Studio 2015, I was getting the infamous [C1001](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/fatal-error-c1001?view=vs-2015) fatal error but through shuffling some surrounding code, it compiled. Never encountered a problem with gcc or clang. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach to [HolyBlackCat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53999020/2069064) is to use function overloading:

```
template <typename> struct tag {};

template <typename T>
constexpr size_t sum(tag<T>) {
    return 0;
}

template <typename T, size_t N>
constexpr size_t sum(tag<Foo<T,N>>) {
    return sum(tag<T>{}) + N;
}
```

Might be a little easier on the eyes. Could also make the functions return `integral_constant`s instead of `size_t`, which has some benefits.

Answer (score 1):

With tag dispatching:

```
template<typename T,size_t N>
class Foo
{
    static constexpr size_t sum_impl(std::true_type) { return N + T::sum(); }
    static constexpr size_t sum_impl(std::false_type) { return N; };
  public:
    static constexpr size_t sum();
};
```

Implementation of `sum`:

```
template<typename T,size_t N>
constexpr size_t Foo<T,N>::sum()
{
    return sum_impl( is_foo<T>{} );
}
```

Comment: I've tried this approach, and indeed it does work on g++ and clang. For some reason, Visual Studio 2015 still tries to compile `sum_impl(std::true_type)` and results in a compiler error when T=double.

Comment: @Matt Shame. [This example](https://godbolt.org/z/ZUr5Vq) seems to work with newer MSVC.

Comment: @Matt Try making the first `sum_impl` a template itself.

Answer (score 0):

What about specializing the full `Foo` class ?

You can also avoid `is_foo`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename, std::size_t N>
struct Foo
 { static constexpr std::size_t sum () { return N; } };

template <typename T, std::size_t N1, std::size_t N2>
struct Foo<Foo<T, N1>, N2>
 { static constexpr std::size_t sum () { return Foo<T, N1>::sum() + N2; } };

int main()
{
    constexpr size_t sum = Foo<Foo<Foo<double,3>,4>,5>::sum(); // 12 = 3+4+5
    std::cout << "sum = " << sum << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**-- EDIT --**

The OP ask:

> In practice, Foo is a large class with many member functions. Would this require redeclaring all of them?

Not necessarily: you can do the trick with a base class/struct of `Foo` (`Bar`, in the following example)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct Foo;

template <typename, std::size_t N>
struct Bar
 { static constexpr std::size_t sum () { return N; } };

template <typename T, std::size_t N1, std::size_t N2>
struct Bar<Foo<T, N1>, N2>
 { static constexpr std::size_t sum () { return Foo<T, N1>::sum() + N2; } };

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct Foo : public Bar<T, N>
 { /* many common member and methods */};

int main()
{
    constexpr size_t sum = Foo<Foo<Foo<double,3>,4>,5>::sum(); // 12 = 3+4+5
    std::cout << "sum = " << sum << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In practice, Foo is a large class with many member functions. Would this require redeclaring all of them?

Comment: @Matt - answer improved; hope this helps.